# java processbuilder x264.exe

Tags: java, processbuilder, x264

i want encoding a video with the x264 out of my own java application.

the problem is that the x264.exe start to work, and than it stop.
the process not terminate, but froze. i try to run the x264 from terminal, that works fine. the problem must be in java.

here my code:

```
String[] command= new String[]{"cmd","/c","x264.exe ....";
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(temp);
Process p = pb.start();
int ev = 0;
if (p.waitFor() != 0)
{
  ev = p.exitValue();
}
```

best regards,
paul

Comment: Try to [redirect output error into a logger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to see what's going on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use the following log to analyse my problem:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(temp);
File log = new File("log");
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(log));
Process p = pb.start();int ev = 0;if (p.waitFor() != 0){ev = p.exitValue();}
```